# 13MHz ISM band vs 433MHz ISM band

Tags: rf, 433mhz

Would [14 MHz ISM Worldwide band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISM_band) have superior range and penetration (equal tx power)capability than the 433 MHz band? In that case, why aren't any transceivers made for this band?

My application is deployed in a forest for collecting data from animals collars. It is expected to work using the 433MHz transceiver by TI I am wondering why I shouldn't use 14MHz band which in contrast is also Worldwide! offering superior characteristics for my application than the 433MHz band.

Comment: If a data collar transmits in a forest and the receiver is out of range, does it make a noise?

Comment: If a man encodes his voice in a digital format and sends it via a data collar in a forest and no woman hears it, is he still wrong? If ... :-)

Comment: I think that is out of the scope of my research. However I can make some room for animals to call their mates in my design so that they dont have to keep on screaming and their calls will be parsed digitally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lower frequencies generally means that receiving antennas have larger effective apertures. This means they collect more power but, of course they have to be bigger in order to match the wavelength of the transmission.

A dipole at 433 MHz is going to be about 30 times smaller than one at 14 MHz of course. This is usually the first reason to go for a higher frequency despite the effective aperture limitations.

I would also imagine bandwidth is important. The allowable bandwidth at 14 MHz is very tiny compared to other ISM bands and this usually means that a practical system will only work over a short range due to overlapping interference from other users.

So, in short, antenna practicalities and interference are the main reasons for not choosing the lower frequency.

Comment: Besides this, there is probably also a regulatory issue. I think that transmitting data is not allowed in 13 MHz, just ISM applications (as an induction heater for example). In contrast 433 MHz can be used for ISM but also for transmitting data at low power.

Comment: 13.56MHz most certainly is used for data - it's the band on which most contactless "swipe cards" are used. See all these "how can I get my RFID reader to work over longer range" questions... So this is a legitimate question and, while long range may be possible with suitable antenna design (and possibly, high transmitter power) it could interfere with any POS terminals in the forest. (If there are any)

Comment: 13MHz is used a lot for transmitting data such as RFID applications etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right, RFID is indeed allowed at 13.56 MHz and I've checked that also generic short range devices (SRD) are allowed at this frequency (at least in Europe). But the range is very limited. Actually the regulations  doesn't talk about a maximum transmitted dBm but a maximum dBuA/m at 10m, as it is expected to be working in the near-field.

Comment: By the way, this is a great answer! saved me.

Comment: A qtr wave monopole antenna is going to be about 5 metres long around 14 MHz. To get the range you have to use this type of antenna I suspect. Mag loop antennas at this freq will have poor range when transmitting because they'll only produce one half of a full EM wave. Ok for receiving though.

Comment: appreciate your time @Andyaka. I understand your view clearly and I accept your view. true. 

Although I have another question and it for my knowledge, is it possible I weave the antenna around the collar? it will be a couple of rounds, in that case, do you think it will be efficient to make an antenna like that?

Comment: An antenna is like a flexible stick held in the hand. If you move your hand up and down slowly the stick (all along its length) follows your hand. If you move your hand too fast the end of the stick remains stationary. If you move your hand at the right speed you'll find that you hardly need to move your hand at all and the end of the stick is moving massively. This last scenario is an antenna being fed the "correct" frequency signal. Wrapping this around that etc is just really hard to analyse. Try it and see - it won't be perfect but it should be tunable to make it work reasonably effective.

Comment: See this http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149577/antenna-vs-coil. You can also "base load" an antenna with an inductor to shorten the effective length of said antenna. This is equivalent to having a really flexible short piece at the hand end of your stick. Try googling solutions.

Comment: Try this: http://www.m0ukd.com/calculators/loaded-quarter-wave-antenna-inductance-calculator/